# How to insert words from a sentence to a list in the correct sequential order

Tags: python, list, text

I have a string/sentence:

```
text = 'Obama and Putin had a meeting today in Russia over lunch where they discussed the new green deal and the Paris agreement.'
```

And I have two lists:

```
sentence_list = []
grouped_words = ['Obama and Putin', 'a meeting', 'today', 'Russia', 'lunch', 'the new green deal', 'the Paris agreement']
```

How can I append the words from `grouped_words` to `sentence_list`, then append the words from the original string `text` that AREN'T equal the words in `grouped_words` to `sentence_list`? The final list would look something like this:

```
['Obama and Putin', 'had', 'a meeting', 'today', 'in','Russia', 'over', 'lunch','where', 'they','discussed', 'the','new green deal', 'and', 'the Paris agreement']
```

This list keeps the contents of `grouped_words` in the same order as the original string while adding the new words that were in the string, also in the same order.

How can I get a list to look like this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are missing some words in grouped_words -- is this intended or no?

Comment: Yes grouped_words is supposed to be missing most of the contents from "text"

Comment: A somewhat inefficient but workable solution might be to split your string by ' ' and matching words against your grouped words list to check if there is a string in grouped words that starts with said word. If yes, append the next word and attempt to continue matching, else put it in the output list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't think of a fancy oneliner so here's a simple loop way:

```
text = 'Obama and Putin had a meeting today in Russia over lunch where they discussed the new green deal and the Paris agreement.'
sentence_list = []
grouped_words = ['Obama and Putin', 'a meeting', 'today', 'Russia', 'lunch', 'the new green deal', 'the Paris agreement']

for i in grouped_words:
    while True:
        if text.startswith(i):
            text = text.replace(i+" ","")
            sentence_list.append(i)
            break
        else:
            new = text.split()[0]
            sentence_list.append(new)
            text = text.replace(new+" ","")

print (sentence_list)

#['Obama and Putin', 'had', 'a meeting', 'today', 'in', 'Russia', 'over', 'lunch', 'where', 'they', 'discussed', 'the new green deal', 'and', 'the Paris agreement']
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a regex to capture substring between two other substrings from `text` and assumes that `text` starts with the first word in `grouped_words`. In the else case you need to have to handle that part.

```
import re

text = 'Obama and Putin had a meeting today in Russia over lunch where they discussed the new green deal and the Paris agreement.'
grouped_words = ['Obama and Putin', 'a meeting', 'today', 'Russia', 'lunch', 'the new green deal', 'the Paris agreement']

lst = [grouped_words[0]]
for x, y in zip(grouped_words, grouped_words[1:]):
    result = re.search(f'{x}(.*){y}', text)
    lst.extend([*result.group(1).strip().split(), y])

print(lst)
# ['Obama and Putin', 'had', 'a meeting', 'today', 'in','Russia', 'over', 'lunch','where', 'they','discussed', 'the','new green deal', 'and', 'the Paris agreement']
```